# how to unit test concurrent rxjava execution

Tags: java, junit, kotlin, rx-java2, mockk

I have two `Completable`s running on two different threads concurrently and accessing shared resources. I want to test their behavior so that only the first one runs certain piece of code and the second ends with error.

Since I am using `Scheduler.trampoline()` in tests, the two `Completable`s cannot run simultaneously, but run in sequence and I am unable to unit test that code.

Example,

```
    val subscription = userRepository.logout().test()
    val subscriptionSimultaneous = userRepository.logout().test()


    subscription
        .assertNoErrors()
        .assertComplete()

    subscriptionSimultaneous
        .assertError(someError)
        .assertNotComplete()

    verify(exactly = 1) { somethingThatMustRunOnlyOnce() }
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually took effort to implement such a test.

```
public class RxTest {
    @Test
    public void testConcurrency() {
        Logout logout = new Logout();

        AtomicInteger logoutCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicInteger errorCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

        Completable logoutCompletable = Completable.fromAction(() -> logout.logout())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnComplete(() -> logoutCount.addAndGet(1))
                .doOnError(error -> errorCount.addAndGet(1))
                .onErrorComplete();
        int tries = 50;
        Completable[] arrayOfLogoutCompletables = new Completable[tries];
        for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
            arrayOfLogoutCompletables[i] = logoutCompletable;
        }
        // run all in parallel and wait for all to finish
        Completable.mergeArray(arrayOfLogoutCompletables).blockingAwait();

        assertEquals(1,logoutCount.get());
        assertEquals(tries - 1, errorCount.get());
    }


    private static class Logout {
        private boolean loggedOut = false;

        /**
         * if you remove synchronized test will fail!!
         */
        private synchronized void logout() {
            if (loggedOut) throw new IllegalStateException();
            loggedOut = true;
        }

    }
}
```

The tests is running up to 50 Completables at the same time on `Schedulers.io()`, each calling `logout()`. There are counters that count how many times `logout()` succeeds and fails. `blockingAwait` is waiting for all Completables to finish.
Run this test 100 times and it will fail maybe 20% percent of the time if you remove `synchronized`. `onErrorComplete()` is there to avoid propagating exception before all Completables finish.

Fun fact: if you add getter and setter to `loggedOut` and use it inside `logout()` it will fail most of the time without `synchronized`.

Hope it helps!